# Flask: Updating template with client side data

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, flask

I am working on a project in which the user is shown a default list of restaurants (rest objs) when they visit a url.  If the user chooses to submit their location using the HTML5 geoloc feature I want to update the results list to make it ordered by proximity to the user's location.

The initial template renders successfully and I can get data back to the server - I just can't re-render the template.  When I preview the response to my client post in the dev console, the data is updated but when I go to the page nothing has changed.

I know I am probably making a silly obvious mistake, I just dont know what it is.

Here is my view:

```
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        lat = request.form.get('lat','')
        lng = request.form.get('lng','')
        query = loc_query(lat,lng,10,0,20)
        rests = Rest.query.from_statement(query).all()
        return render_template('main.html',rests = rests)
    else:
        rests = getLatest(5)#Get 5 random rest objects 
        return render_template('main.html',rests = rests)
```

And here is my client script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function sendloco (loc) {

        $.post('/latest',{lat:loc.coords.latitude,lng:loc.coords.longitude}, 
            function(data){
                $('#restlist').html(data);
            });                 
    };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sendloco);
</script>
```

And here is the relevant part of my template:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" id="restlist">

        {% for rest in rests %}
            <h2><b><a href="{{ url_for('profile',id=rest.id)}}">{{ rest.name }}</a></b></h2>
            <h3>Date:{{ rest.latestDt() }}</h3>
            <h3>{{ rest.street }}</h3>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Thansk fo the help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling `$('.restlist').html(data)` but in html your div has `id="restlist"` not class. Perhaps try `$('#restlist').html(data)`.

Comment: Hey thanks @jsm1th yes good catch (code updated). I still have the same issue.

Comment: @user2957824 You don't have full code available on git by any chance do you?